# Using C++ header file in vb.net app?

Tags: c++, vb.net, header-files

What is the simplest way to use a C++ header file in a VB.NET application?
I need to access an API defined via the header file for a custom VB.NET windows app.

Answer (score 1):

Use the VB.NET [Declare statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4zey12w5.aspx) to redeclare the API function in your code.  This will not work if the header file contains classes, you'll need to [write a wrapper](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mcpp/ManagedWrapperSample.aspx) to make those usable.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [PInvoke Interop Assistant](http://www.codeplex.com/clrinterop/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=14120) to convert the C++ header into PInvoke declarations.

If you have the full source code for the C++ project use [C++ Interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2x8kf7zx%28VS.80%29.aspx?ppud=4) as advised by whunmr.

Comment: MarkJ, thank you for your reply to this question!  I can only hope schooner decides to go back and mark this as the answer.  The SigImp Translate Snippet tab of the PInvoke Interop Assistant saved me an awful lot of time!